# magento 2.2 : how to make a ajax add to cart in magento 2.2 site from an external site

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento2.2, magento-2.1.7

I need to do an add to cart in a Magento2.2 site from an external site using ajax. I am using the following ajax code.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://local.magento.com/test_us_en/checkout/cart/add/",
                type: "POST",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:{
            product: 1,
            form_key:tju8cas1gG61phY6,
            qty:2,
        },
        success: function(data) {            
        console.log(data);
         },
         error: function() {
         }
});
```

please help me.

Comment: is the "external site" another platform (say, cms?) running on the same domain? otherwise you will have huge xss challenges doing it over ajax.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to Cart from  external site.

I want to suggest to you use ***Magento 2 REST API*** instead Magento own  frontend Cart system.

**For your current code, you will get Form_key issue as  you have trying to cart from external site**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/list.html